# how to configure apache to proxy from /blog to another site on another server

Tags: apache, proxy

I manage a site that runs java and would like to host my blog on a different server for security and seo reasons.  My site currently has a link for a blog and the url displays /blog in the address bar, what I would like to do is proxy that link over to my blog hosted on another server.  Not sure if proxying through apache is the correct approach but never the less this is what I was asked to do.

Essentially I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
ProxyPass /blog https://mynewblog.com/
ProxyPassReverse /blog https://mynewblog.com/
```

Can someone please help or throw a bone my way to figure this out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anything in the error log?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my problem.  This may help someone else out in the future.  This worked for me.

```
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
<Location "/blog">
ProxyPass "https://mynewblog.com/"
ProxyPassReverse "https://mynewblog.com/"
</Location>
```